# Problems with speeds on Access point

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point

I am having an issue with the speeds on my Access point.
First I will explain my set up.

- My main router (recently installed) is an Asus GS-AX3000, replacing a TP-Link Archer AX1800.
- I set the TP-Link up in AP Mode, and plugged an ethernet cable from a LAN port on the GS-AX3000 to the WAN port on the TP-Link AP.
- I have different SSIDs for both the main router and the AP.
- I am on the 500 Mbps down / 125 Mbps up from my ISP (Fiber).

I get the full speeds on my main router but seems I am only getting 100-200 on the AP if that. Is there something I can check or possibly have something set up incorrectly? When the TP-Link was my main router, I was also seeing speeds of 500 Mbps so I know it is capable.

I am in no way an expert at this stuff, but not completely lost either.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: wifi is tricky ... interference from neighbours wifi on the same or adjacent channels can have a huge impact on speed ...

Comment: https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-ax1800/#specifications looks like its all gigabit ports

Comment: Did you make sure your TP-Link is no longer doing NAT? You want it to transparently bridge traffic from its Wi-Fi clients to the upstream router. And as someone else mentioned, make sure you're on a clean channel. If both of those APs support 160MHz-wide channels, it might be tough to find two clean channels that wide.

Comment: I will check on the NAT on the TP Link. I know the Asus supports 160Mhz, but I do not believe the TP Link does. Interference isn't a huge problem where I live, fair amount of distance between houses, but I will check that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, In AP mode there is not much I can manually configure. No reference to NAT available, and nothing is on the same channel. Ran a speed test tonight while there was no usage and still only maxing out at around 98mbps. Tomorrow I am going to check the cable / wire run again.

Comment: I believe my issue is the cable. This was the very 1st cable I ran way back when and I think it is cat 5, not cat 5e.

Comment: Welp, thats not it, the cable is Cat 5e. One thing I noticed today when connected to the AP's ssid on my android phone, is it showed that I was connected at 720 mbps but ran the speed test and still maxing out at 99-100 mbps. 100 mbps is more than enough for my needs, it's just principle at this point, what is causing this?